# how to obtain histogram data in Matlab

Tags: matlab

As we know, 'hist' function in Matlab plots the histogram of an array. I need to know the numerical value of each bin. Could you help me please?

thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Specify an output for [`hist`](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/hist.html).

```
[h,bins]=hist(data)
```

will get you what you want.