# how to store the value of a histogram having unequal bins width

Tags: matlab

How can I store the value of each bin interval in a variable. For example I want to store the bin value between interval -10 and -5 in a variable say `a`.

Comment: Have a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3096391/426834

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to construct unequal width histograms with Matlab?? ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2379230/how-to-construct-unequal-width-histograms-with-matlab)

Comment: In the question linked by Amro, the answer shows how you can store the values of each bin interval in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

The `hist` function can also return values. Try `help hist`.